# Typescript Types. Describe a Type of Generic Function Parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Can somebody please help me. How can I run this typescript code without issues at type checking?

```js
type FuncsType = {
    name1(argv1: string, argv2: string): void;
    name2(argv1: number, argv2: number): void;
};

const functions: FuncsType = {
    name1: (argv1, argv2) => {
        console.log(argv1, argv2);
    },
    name2: (argv1, argv2) => {
        console.log(argv1, argv2);
    }
};

type start = (name: keyof FuncsType, ...args: Parameters<FuncsType[keyof FuncsType]>) => void;

const start: start = (name, ...args) => {
    const func = functions[name] as FuncsType[keyof FuncsType];
    func(...args);
};

start("name1", "1", "2");
start("name2", 3, 2);
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPxSZ.png)

I found out that the problem no longer occurs when I specify the rest arguments of a certain function.

[success hack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UnIe.png)

Comment: Please post the code and error as text, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

So, in principle you could just do the following and get the same result with the benefit of being less verbose and clearer about your intentions.

```
function start(args: number[] | string[]): void {
    console.log(args);
}

start(['1', '2']);
start([3, 2]);
```

I personally prefer to provide an array as an argument and be explicit about what it is I am providing, instead of saying: "Here. Take the remaining arguments", which is what you are doing if you're using the spread operator.

Now let's say you want to do something more than just `console.log()` something and you actually want to call a separate function based on  a condition. I understand your desire to put this in an object, but I'd personally just make check for the contents of your args like this:

```
function start(args: number[] | string[]): void {
   args.forEach(arg => {
       if (arg === typeof 'string') {
           // do something
       }
       if (arg === typeof 'number') {
           // do something else
       }
   });
}
```

I'm personally not a fan of using objects to look up functions...

In my opinion you also don't need to type your functions. So I wouldn't worry too much about doing things like this:

```
const start: start = () => {}
```

I would however advise on communicating a functions return type, so in this case omitting the function type and showing the return type:

```
const start = (): void => {}
```

TypeScript is about readability for me, so I try to be clear and communicate with others (and my future self) by using types, but I try to avoid complex generics and unions until I really need them.

Now, a quick word about the spread operator `(...)` for arrays in JavaScript:

```
const array = [1,2,3,4,5]
console.log(array) // [1,2,3,4,5]
```

is exactly the same as saying:

```
const array = [1,2,3,4,5]
console.log([...array]) // [1,2,3,4,5]
```

**Note:** If you don't provide the square brackets, you will actually just get the numbers and NOT an array.

```
const array = [1,2,3,4,5]
console.log(...array) // 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

On a sidenote Optional Parameters or types can be marked with a '?'

as in:

```
class SomeClass

    myVariable1?: string; // can be omitted when calling the constructor new 
    myVariable2: Number;  // SomeClass(1) or not new SomeClass("somestring", 2);

    constructor(omittableConstructorParameter1?:string, 
    notOmittableConstructorParameter2:Number) {
       this.myVariable1 = ommitableConstructorArgument;
       this.myVariable2 = notOmmitableConstructorArgument;
    }
```

this concept applies to Interfaces, too (ofc without the constructor)